# Ultrasonic dual transmitter-receiver circuit

Tags: piezo, max232, flow-sensor

I am building an ultrasonic flow sensor, based on piezoelectric actuators from cheap HR-SR04 modules. I need to measure the speed of sound back and forth. Schematic like this is good to send pulses:
[image]

But then I need to switch this transmitter and receiver actuator. How to do this? Use mux? Or there is some generic driver schematic, which combines high-voltage sender circuit plus input amp?

Comment: Have a look at the [SRF04 module schematic](https://www.robot-electronics.co.uk/htm/srf04tech.htm). These modules are so cheap that it's not worth doing your own design. The circuit you've shown uses a chip designed for RS232 serial line level conversion so it is either very clever or totally bonkers. I don't know which.

Comment: @transistor Note that the MAX232 chip is used in the SRF04 to generate a higher voltage drive for the transmitting transducer. The schematic shown in the question is not as complete as that in the SRF04.

Comment: I didn't notice that. I had been looking at the modules earlier in the evening before the question was posted. OK, I've decided that it's very clever then.